# Adding padding to submit buttons on Mac OS X

Tags: html, css, input, padding

I'm having trouble adding padding to a submit button. I've created an ultra simple example in a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxr197pa/1/

Here's the code for it:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

CSS:

```
input {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I must just not be getting something really simple, and I'm kind of embarrassed I can't figure it out. It seems like no one else is having this problem, as I've searched quite extensively. I've even seen examples of people adding padding with no issues. Would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

## Update

To clarify the problem for those who might be confused by what I'm asking: the code above doesn't alter the padding of the button in any way. It appears there's default padding applied to the button, but the padding I've specified simply doesn't show. Here's a picture depicting what I see when I enter the code above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyASx.png

This issue has been fixed in an answer below, but the underlying cause is still a mystery to me. It appears to have something to do with my computer. I'm using a fully up to date Mac OS X. My PC, on the other hand, renders the example above completely normally. It doesn't matter what browser I use on my Mac either, it still doesn't render the padding that I'm specifying.

That's not the end of the story though, because after analyzing the source code on other websites, I found submit buttons that were rendering padding correctly on my Mac, with effectively identical code. See here:

http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-14/styling-submit-buttons.html

So why is the padding being rendered sometimes and not others?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Strange that something as simple as padding wouldn't work in all browsers, but your example looks good to me on chromium http://i.imgur.com/hKE16R3.png

Comment: Chrome Ver. 40.0.2214.115 on OS X (10.10.2)

Comment: So what are you wanting? - you don't says what's actually wrong in the fiddle example.

Comment: @Tom Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/378nmhow/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yep, that worked. I also checked it on my PC and the example I left worked...anyone know what the deal is? It must be my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments above, you said you're on a Mac (OS X)..

Therefore you need to set the the `appearance` property of the `input` element to `none` in order for the padding to work. I went ahead and added `-webkit`/`-moz` vendor prefixed properties too:

```css
input {
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

This just seems to be one of those strange cross-browser inconsistencies, because this doesn't appear to be an issue on Windows.

Comment: @Sachin Are you sure? Based on [Tom's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801374/adding-padding-to-submit-buttons?noredirect=1#comment45876743_28801374), it worked. I'm going to fire up my Mac to see if there is some soft of browser option that is controlling this.

Comment: @JoshCrozier This worked for me, Josh. Wow, what a weird issue. Would you recommend using `button` instead of `<input type="submit" />`? This seems like such a fundamental element, and I figured that all browsers would've figured out how to implement it uniformly by now.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you cannot add padding to an input.

I think the closest you can get is increasing the height and the width of the input.