# How to correct CSS differences for different OS in Semantic UI React? I am having issues with Form.Select in Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using Form.Select from Semantic UI React and seeing different behavior based on the OS. I have tested on macOS and Windows and the issue occurs when  tag is used inside  and not passed as a options prop. Code is as follows -

```
          <Form.Field label='An HTML <select>' control='select'>
           <option value='male'>Male</option>
           <option value='female'>Female</option>
          </Form.Field>
```

It looks different on the documentation too, here is a link - https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-field-control-html but I am also attaching screenshots -

1. **Chrome on macOS**

[image: Chrome on macOS]

2. **Safari on macOS**

[image: Safari on macOS]

3. **Chrome on Windows**

[image: Chrome on Windows]

Please let me know if anyone has a solution and I can also open an issue on GitHub repo but thought it will be faster to get a response here.

**Edit 1**: Added Windows screenshot.

**Edit 2**: Added 'in Semantic UI React' to the question header.

Comment: The issue is padding not getting applied to <select> on macOS, I found this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801374/adding-padding-to-submit-buttons-on-mac-os-x but doing this also hides the arrow on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those examples are just showing that you can still use native html tags with the child api and field control if there was a reason you were needing to do so. Those html tags do not have any of the Semantic UI class names applied to them when they are rendered into your DOM so they only have the native styling for whatever platform you are on.

I would recommend that you don't render those as native HTML tags unless there is some technical reason you need to. For consistent styling across OS/Browser, using Semantic UI React components will give you the class names you need for consistency. Either of the below will work:

```
const options = [
  {key: 'male', value: 'male', text: 'Male'},
  {key: 'female', value: 'female', text: 'Female'},
]
<Form.Field>
  <label>A Semantic UI Form.Field and Select component</label>
  <Select options={options} search />
</Form.Field>

// or

<Form.Select
  label='A Semantic UI Form.Select component'
  options={options}
  search
/>
```

[Here is a working Codesandbox example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/13k6jy7q73)

Comment: When using SUIR components I am not able to use keyboard to select the options and that is a functionality I would like to have. For few options SUIR componet would have been great but I am using it to select countries. For example, in the docs I cannot toggle between Male and Female using M and  F keys when SUIR is used. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the answer with a codesandbox example. All of the accessibility requirements you just described are part of SUI and SUIR. The only thing that I changed was the need to add a boolean `search` prop to the Select component for being able to narrow results with letters.

Comment: So I tried using what you recommended but when I try to get the value using event.target.value I do not get the value of the country I selected in the dropdown. I was able to get it earlier. What am I doing wrong? [Here is a Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2178qrq50n)

Comment: Don't mind. I found the correct way to get the value here - https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/798.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that @brianespinosa suggested makes the select look same across all the browsers and platforms and also has the search functionality. I found a solution that works for me but I do not know if it is something recommened by the SUIR team. I would like to know their thoughts on this. Here is my solution -

```
<Form.Field as='select' className="ui dropdown">
 <option value='default'>Select your country</option>
 {
  countries.map(country => {
   return (
    <option key={country['alpha-2']} value={country['alpha-2']}>
     {country['name']}
    </option>
   )
  })
 }
</Form.Field>
```

The only reason I chose this solution is because this allows the user to select options using the keyborad.

Comment: Your solution works doing the exact same thing, just with more code. The above codesandbox I gave you example ALSO allows you to use your keyboard to select users the exact same way. Do whichever you feel more comfortable with.